# Inconsistent Result - Update versus Select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm running the below statement and can't understand why the `update` affects 0 rows while a `select` with the same join and `where` return 1 row. They are both of type `Varchar` and crmnumberAC is bigger so should be able to take the string from AccountNumber. Thoughts?

```
begin transaction
update c
set c.crmnumberAC = a.AccountNumber
--select a.name, a.AccountNumber, c.fullname, c.crmnumberAC 
from Contact as c
right join Account as a
    on c.PFH_Mapping_Ac_ContacId = a.AccountId
WHERE (a.AccountNumber IS NOT NULL AND c.crmnumberAC IS NULL) 
    OR a.AccountNumber != c.crmnumberAC
rollback transaction
```

This is the result set when I uncomment the `select` and just run that as far as the `where`;

[image]

Comment: Why do you have a rollback statement? Perhaps you undo your own update?

Comment: Rollback is just for testing before committing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see, your `SELECT` doesn't return anything from the table Contact, the table you are trying to `UPDATE`.

The `SELECT` returns a row just because you have a right join, but in table Contact you have no row that fulfill the where condition.

Comment: sometimes a pair of fresh eyes is all you need :)